# Autolayout issue with collectionview cell

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

I am having custom UIcollectionviewCell with 1 button and 3 labels.
I need to set proper autolayout for design.
here is my fisrt image which is going to be show all 4 labels 
[1. Image From Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDU6M.png)

In this the **fisrt label** need to be resize width upto some maximum width. When content reach to the maximum width the content should be with [...].
The **second label** have to stick with first label with 20px horizontal space from first label 
 and **third label** need to be stick width second label with 10 px. 
 The **second and third label** have fix character length i.e 5
 i have try some constraint like. 
[2nd Label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jrgj.png)
[1st label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4a20L.png)
[3rd label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpvhR.png)
[3rd label [other constraint]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tp4Ah.png)
[2nd label [other constraint]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVnsC.png)
By set this constarints i am getting o/p 
[then o/p of current constraint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhnSL.png)
Can anyone need to find solution how can i reach this constarint?[Need o/p like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwiKy.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just set width of label 2 and label 3 and button. Label 1 will spread to left space.

[image: Label 1]

[image: Label 2]

[image: Label 3]

Comment: Is the First label get truncate?

Comment: yes. You can set this property in attributes inspector.

Comment: By this set up constraint i get label 1 width 0. I have also set numberof line = 1 and line break mode = truncate tail.

Comment: Yes. Because you give trailing and leading constraint with lbl2 and button. And lbl2 and button have fix width. That's way Label1 automatically spread to rest space.

Comment: Then how can i set label 1 to set max width with truncate content?

Comment: Label1 width set to maximum with truncate content

Comment: Okay.. but how can i set label to maximum width ?

Comment: What is meaning of maximum width here. Label 1 is already set to maximum width.

Comment: we add leading and trailing constraint to label1 therefore it's width can't be 0

Comment: Yes u are right. but here i am getting width 0 of label 1.and plz note that this cell will display in screen with contentview.width / 2. If i am showing full contentview then its work well as earlier. but after dividing contentview height with /2 its become 0 width of label 1.

Comment: you must missing some constraint. Pls check with image and add leading constraint of button as well. If it still not works than share your code so i can check what is missing.